# Run a cron job on the first Monday of every month?

Tags: cron, crontab

I'd like to run a job from cron at 8.30 on the first Monday of every month.  The cron Wikipedia page says

> While normally the job is executed when the time/date specification fields all match 
>       the current time and date, there is one exception: if both "day of month" and 
>       "day of week" are restricted (not "*"), then **either** the "day of month" field (3) 
>       or the "day of week" field (5) must match the current day.

(my emphasis)

Does that mean I can't do the first Monday of the month, I can only do the first (or whatever) day of the month?  I can't think of a way round it.

Comment: slhck - that sounds like a good solution - would you mind expanding it into an answer with the full code?  then i'll mark it as correct :)

Comment: Similar answer in https://superuser.com/questions/1042805/how-to-set-cron-expression-to-run-first-weekday-mon-fri-and-first-weekend-sat

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can put the condition into the actual crontab command (generic way):

```
[ "$(date '+%u')" = "1" ] && echo "It's Monday"
```

if your locale is EN/US, you can also compare strings (initial answer):

```
[ "$(date '+%a')" = "Mon" ] && echo "It's Monday"
```

---

Now, if this condition is true on one of the first seven days in a month, you have its first Monday. Note that in the crontab, the percent-syntax needs to be escaped though (generic way):

```
0   12  1-7 *   *   [ "$(date '+\%u')" = "1" ] && echo "It's Monday"
```

if your locale is EN/US, you can also compare strings (initial answer):

```
0   12  1-7 *   *   [ "$(date '+\%a')" = "Mon" ] && echo "It's Monday"
```

Replace the `echo` command with the actual command you want to run. I found a [similar approach](http://www.switchplane.com/blog/how-to-run-a-cron-job-on-the-first-weekday-of-the-month.php) too.

Comment: actually, slhck, i spoke too soon - this isn't working in my crontab: it seems to have a problem with the date test for some reason.  This works in the command line `[ "$(date '+%a')" = "Mon" ] && echo "It's Monday"` as does `[ $(date '+%a') = "Mon" ] && echo "It's Monday"`  But, in the crontab it seems to be failing at this test.  I can't get at any useful feedback from cron either:  i'm trying this `[ "$(date '+%a')" = "Tue" ] >> /home/deploy/cron.log 2>&1` to capture any error output into a log but that's not working either :/

Comment: Hm. Can you check whether the `date` output is correct? For example, just let a `cron` command run that outputs this to a file: `date '+%a' > ~/datetest 2>&1` – then check if that resulted in the right string to compare against.

Comment: I found the problem - the percent in `+%a` needed escaping when it was in the crontab, ie the line needed to be this:  `[ "$(date '+\%a')" = "Mon" ] && echo "It's Monday"`.  If you could update your answer with that it would be helpful to future readers :) Thanks again - max

Comment: Oh, now I see why. Glad it works now, thanks for trying it out!

Comment: Beware that for alpine's CRON implementation, the percent sign **needs not** to be escaped.

Answer (score 29):

I have a computer with locale on Spanish, so, this approach isn't working for me because **mon** changes to **lun**

Other languages would fail as well, so, I did a slight variation on the accepted answer that takes out the language barrier:

```
 0 9 1-7 * *   [ "$(date '+\%u')" = "1" ] && echo "¡Es lunes!"
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I have a Dutch locale which also uses different names for weekdays. And using numbers also feels cleaner than comparing strings to determine the day of the week.

Answer (score 11):

I find it easier when there's no need to handle day numbers.

Run First Monday of month:

```
0 2 * * 1 [ `date '+\%m'` == `date '+\%m' -d "1 week ago"` ] || /path/to/command
```

i.e. if the month 1 week ago is not the same as the current month then we are on the 1st day 1 (= Monday) of the month.

Similarly, for the Third Friday

```
0 2 * * 6 [ `date '+\%m'` == `date '+\%m' -d "3 weeks ago"` ] || /path/to/command
```

i.e. if the month 3 weeks ago is different to current month then we are on the 3rd day 6 (= Friday) of the month

Comment: Day 6 of week is Saturday not Friday.

Answer (score 7):

Since I interpret my cron statements using php and js, I can't use bash. Finally I found that it *is* in fact possible with just cron:

```
0 30 8 * 1/1 MON#1
```

Hope this helps someone else. Regardless, I wish you all a beautiful day. :-)

Comment: This is not cron, it's possibly quartz

Comment: According to https://crontab.cronhub.io/ it is cron. Can also try 0 0 8 ? * 1#1 *

Answer (score 5):

I have scheduled a job to run on the 4th Monday of every month at 4:00 PM as follows:

```
0 16 22-28 * Mon [ "$(date '+\%a')" == "Mon" ] && touch /home/me/FourthMonOfMonth.txt
```

Comment: Would have the same effect as 0 16 22-28 * * , but would run four times a month more.

Answer (score 5):

There is a hacky way to do this with a classic (Vixie, Debian) cron:

```
30 8 */100,1-7 * MON
```

The day-of-month field starts with a star (`*`), and so cron considers it "unrestricted" and uses the AND logic between the day-of-month and the day-of-week fields.

`*/100` means "every 100 days starting from date 1". Since there are no months with more than 100 days, `*/100,1-7` effectively means "on dates 1 to 7".

Here's my article with more details: [Schedule Cronjob for the First Monday of Every Month, the Funky Way](https://blog.healthchecks.io/2022/09/schedule-cron-job-the-funky-way/)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use

```
"$(/bin/date '+%\w')" = "1"
```

instead of

```
"$(date '+\%a')" = "Mon"
```

to avoid locale problem.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is NOT possible using only crontab, however one can use a wrapper function to pick the correct day from a "first seven days of month" contab entry; see [this](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/2551-crontab-first-monday-month-only.html) from entry.

The wrapper script would be

```
#! /usr/bin/ksh
day=$(date +%d)
if ((day <= 7)) ; then
   exec somecommand
fi
exit 1
```

and you would need to run it (assuming it is called wrapper.sh and globally available) using the crontab entry

```
0 0 * * 1 wrapper.sh
```

Comment: thanks elemaki.  I thought about a similar solution using some extra code inside the task that gets run, getting it to test whether it's the first monday of the month inside the script, and then calling it every monday in crontab. It's a ruby script so it's easy to test the day of th week. But i was hoping there'd be a crontab only way.

Answer (score 1):

On Solaris 10 I had to format the condition as follows:

```
[ `date +\%a` = "Sat" ] && echo "It's Saturday"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try running cronjob for first seven days of month and let it execute only on Monday.

```
30 8 * * 1 [`date +\%d` -le 07] && <job>
```

Above should work for you.

Comment: +1 more success hit ration then to run for the first week and check for Monday. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The day of month field here is */100,1-7, meaning “every 100 days starting from date 1, and also on dates 1-7”. Since there are no months with 100+ days, this again is a trick to say “on dates 1 to 7” but with a leading star. Because of the star, cron will run the command on dates 1 to 7 that are also Monday.

0 22 */100,1-7 * 2

On the cron guru example below, you can see the result and the next run date.

https://crontab.guru/#0_0_*/100,1-7_*_MON

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This answer expands on @ChiragPansheriya's [answer to this same question](https://superuser.com/a/1761656).

## tl;dr

Do a quick test of your cron implementation by pasting this into your crontab:

```bash
# For 1st Monday (or Tuesday, etc) of month, use */32,1-7 for days of month
# For 2nd Monday (or Tuesday, etc) of month, use */32,8-14 for days of month
# For 3rd Monday (or Tuesday, etc) of month, use */32,15-21 for days of month
# For 4th Monday (or Tuesday, etc) of month, use */32,22-28 for days of month
# For 5th Monday (or Tuesday, etc) of month, use */32,29-31 for days of month
# Explanation: https://superuser.com/a/1813556
* * */32,1-7   * 0  echo "First Sunday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,8-14  * 0  echo "Second Sunday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,15-21 * 0  echo "Third Sunday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,22-28 * 0  echo "Fourth Sunday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,29-31 * 0  echo "Fifth Sunday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,1-7   * 1  echo "First Monday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,8-14  * 1  echo "Second Monday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,15-21 * 1  echo "Third Monday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,22-28 * 1  echo "Fourth Monday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,29-31 * 1  echo "Fifth Monday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,1-7   * 2  echo "First Tuesday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,8-14  * 2  echo "Second Tuesday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,15-21 * 2  echo "Third Tuesday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,22-28 * 2  echo "Fourth Tuesday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,29-31 * 2  echo "Fifth Tuesday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,1-7   * 3  echo "First Wednesday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,8-14  * 3  echo "Second Wednesday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,15-21 * 3  echo "Third Wednesday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,22-28 * 3  echo "Fourth Wednesday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,29-31 * 3  echo "Fifth Wednesday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,1-7   * 4  echo "First Thursday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,8-14  * 4  echo "Second Thursday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,15-21 * 4  echo "Third Thursday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,22-28 * 4  echo "Fourth Thursday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,29-31 * 4  echo "Fifth Thursday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,1-7   * 5  echo "First Friday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,8-14  * 5  echo "Second Friday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,15-21 * 5  echo "Third Friday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,22-28 * 5  echo "Fourth Friday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,29-31 * 5  echo "Fifth Friday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,1-7   * 6  echo "First Saturday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,8-14  * 6  echo "Second Saturday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,15-21 * 6  echo "Third Saturday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,22-28 * 6  echo "Fourth Saturday" >>cron_out.txt
* * */32,29-31 * 6  echo "Fifth Saturday" >>cron_out.txt
```

## Explanation

One might wonder:

> The `*/32` element in the *days of month* field is always false (no month has more than 31 days), so why include it?

It turns out that, if the *first* character of the *days of month* or *days of week* fields is an asterisk (`*`), cron switches from taking the *union* of the *days of month* and *days of week* fields, to taking their *intersection*. The `*/32` element is there simply to trigger this change in behavior.

This is hinted at in the man page for *cronie* [née](https://web.archive.org/web/20150914183137/https://fedorahosted.org/cronie/ticket/1) *vixie-cron*:

> Note: The day of a command's execution can be specified in the following two fields — 'day of month', and 'day of week'.  If both fields are restricted (i.e., do not contain the "*" character), the command will be run when either field matches the current time.  For example,
> "30 4 1,15 * 5" would cause a command to be run at 4:30 am on the 1st and 15th of each month, plus every Friday.
> — https://www.mankier.com/5/crontab

The converse is that, if *day of month* or *day of week* *do* contain the `*` character, the command will be run only when *both* fields match the current time.

You can see how the presence of the leading `*` character in the *days of month* field changes [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/)'s interpretation:

| crontab entry specification | crontab guru's interpretation |
| --- | --- |
| [`0 8 1-7 * 1`](https://crontab.guru/#0_8_1-7_*_1) | *At 08:00 on every day-of-month from 1 through 7 and on Monday.* |
| [`0 8 */32,1-7 * 1`](https://crontab.guru/#0_8_*/32,1-7_*_1) | *At 08:00 on every 32nd day-of-month and every day-of-month from 1 through 7 if it's on Monday.* |

## Examining the source code

The phrase used in the man page, *"contain the `*` character,"* is ambiguous. Does it mean, *consist solely of the `*` character?* Or does it mean, *contain the `*` character at any point within the field?* Consulting the source code for vixie cron ([entry.c](https://github.com/svagner/vixie-cron/blob/13d13f0b38d73e7a415caa77b5821be92dd16f70/entry.c#L193)), we see that the `DOM_STAR` and `DOW_STAR` flags get set if the *first* character of their respective fields is an asterisk (`*`).

```c
/* DOM (days of month)
*/

if (ch == '*')
    e->flags |= DOM_STAR;                    ①
ch = get_list(e->dom, FIRST_DOM, LAST_DOM,
              PPC_NULL, ch, file);
if (ch == EOF) {
    ecode = e_dom;
    goto eof;
}

[...]

/* DOW (days of week)
*/

if (ch == '*')
    e->flags |= DOW_STAR;                    ②
ch = get_list(e->dow, FIRST_DOW, LAST_DOW,
              DowNames, ch, file);
if (ch == EOF) {
    ecode = e_dow;
    goto eof;
}
```

① The `DOM_STAR` flag gets set if the first character of the *days of month* field is a `*` character
② The `DOW_STAR` flag gets set if the first character of the *days of week* field is a `*` character

Later, in [`cron.c`](https://github.com/svagner/vixie-cron/blob/13d13f0b38d73e7a415caa77b5821be92dd16f70/cron.c), if either of those two flags are set, cron switches the logical operator between the *days of month* and *days of week* fields from an OR to an AND:

```c
/* the dom/dow situation is odd.  '* * 1,15 * Sun' will run on the
 * first and fifteenth AND every Sunday;  '* * * * Sun' will run *only*
 * on Sundays;  '* * 1,15 * *' will run *only* the 1st and 15th.  this
 * is why we keep 'e->dow_star' and 'e->dom_star'.  yes, it's bizarre.
 * like many bizarre things, it's the standard.
 */
for (u = db->head;  u != NULL;  u = u->next) {
    for (e = u->crontab;  e != NULL;  e = e->next) {
        Debug(DSCH|DEXT, ("user [%s:%d:%d:...] cmd=\"%s\"\n",
                          env_get("LOGNAME", e->envp),
                          e->uid, e->gid, e->cmd))
        if (bit_test(e->minute, minute) &&
                bit_test(e->hour, hour) &&
                bit_test(e->month, month) &&
                ( ((e->flags & DOM_STAR) || (e->flags & DOW_STAR))        ①
                  ? (bit_test(e->dow,dow) && bit_test(e->dom,dom))        ②
                  : (bit_test(e->dow,dow) || bit_test(e->dom,dom)))) {    ③
            if ((doNonWild && !(e->flags & (MIN_STAR|HR_STAR)))
                    || (doWild && (e->flags & (MIN_STAR|HR_STAR))))
                job_add(e, u);
        }
    }
}
```

① The `DOM_STAR` and `DOW_STAR` flags are tested
② OR logical operator causes a *union* of the *days of month* and *days of week* fields
③ AND logical operator causes an *intersection* of the *days of month* and *days of week* fields

We've seen here that the *"contain the `*` character"* test mentioned in the man page, is actually a test of whether the `*` character is the *first* character of the field.

Caution: This behavior is not mandated by POSIX, as far as I can tell. (See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/crontab.html). YMMV depending on your cron implementation. I can confirm that the technique described in this answer works on *cronie* (a *vixie-cron* derivative). It is also understood by crontab.guru (example: [`0 8 */32,1-7 * 1`](https://crontab.guru/#0_8_*/32,1-7_*_1)).

Some background information on this behavior is included in the [FEATURES](https://github.com/svagner/vixie-cron/blob/13d13f0b38d73e7a415caa77b5821be92dd16f70/FEATURES#L76) file in the vixie cron source code:

```
--  the dom/dow situation is odd.  '* * 1,15 * Sun' will run on the
    first and fifteenth AND every Sunday;  '* * * * Sun' will run *only*
    on Sundays;  '* * 1,15 * *' will run *only* the 1st and 15th.  this
    is why we keep 'e->dow_star' and 'e->dom_star'.  I didn't think up
    this behaviour; it's how cron has always worked but the documentation
    hasn't been very clear.  I have been told that some AT&T crons do not
    act this way and do the more reasonable thing, which is (IMHO) to "or"
    the various field-matches together.  In that sense this cron may not
    be completely similar to some AT&T crons.
```

## Comparison

Here's a comparison of how the two approaches look in a crontab:

```
0 8 1-7 * *       [ "$(date '+\%u')" = "1" ] && echo "First Monday"
0 8 */32,1-7 * 1  echo "First Monday"
```

(The first line shows the approach of the [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/q/428807)).

## Related discussions

- **Why crontab uses OR when both day of month and day of week specified?**
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51342252
- **Are the "day of month" and "day of week" crontab fields mutually exclusive?**
  https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/602328

Answer (score 0):

I made a general solution for this kind of problems, it works for first, second, third..... last weekday of the month.

You can use it like this:

```
30 06 * * Mon run-if-today 1 "Mon" && echo "First Monday"
30 06 * * Thu run-if-today 3 "Thu" && echo "Third Thursday"
30 06 * * Sun run-if-today L "Sun" && echo "Last Sunday"
```

The script run-if-today check for both the weekday and the desired week date range, if both match then it returns 0, otherwise 1.

Check the code here. https://github.com/xr09/cron-last-sunday

Answer (score 0):

This usage should be most universal and avoids the locale issue.

```
[ `/bin/date +\%u` -eq 1 ]
```

the first Monday of the month at 6am would look like this in `/etc/crontab`

```
00 6 1-7 * *    root    [ `/bin/date +\%u` -eq 1 ] && /run/yourjob.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

```
crontab 30 8 */27 * 1
```

At 08:30 AM, [ones] every 27 days, and on Monday
(see [crontab expression generator](https://crontabkit.com/crontab-expression-generator))

Day of the month is *unencumbered* (***is*** *), so the ***either*** logic/exception *does not* apply.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this and here is what I came up with:

```
0 11 * * 1#1 - Run at 11 am on the first Monday of every month
0 11 * * 1#2 - Run at 11 am on the second Monday of every month
0 11 * * 1#3 - Run at 11 am on the third Monday of every month
```

If you wanted to run on Tuesday instead:

```
0 11 * * 2#1 - Run at 11 am on the first Tuesday of every month
0 11 * * 2#2 - Run at 11 am on the second Tuesday of every month
0 11 * * 2#3 - Run at 11 am on the third Tuesday of every month
```

Comment: Is it some cron dialect? What sort of cron is it for? This fails check in vixie-cron.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this solves the problem more elegantly:

```
30 8 1-7 * 1 /run/your/job.sh
```

Comment: Doh! : "If  both  fields  are  restricted  (ie, aren't  *),  the command will be run when either field matches the current time."

Comment: Also on February (the one that ends 28th) it will not be run every 4 years.

Comment: "either" means any of them, not "both". this will run every day for the 1st 7 days of the month.

Comment: This row would run a command on the first to seventh of each month, as well as on every Monday

Answer (score -1):

I needed the same result, but wanted to use pure cron. I hope this improves on the accepted answer.

For me I needed it to run the **First Monday of each month at noon.**

So this should run: At Noon, in the first 7 days of the month, on a Monday:
0 12 1-7 * 1

https://crontab.guru/#0_12_1-7_*_1

Comment: from the guru: `“At 12:00 on every day-of-month from 1 through 7 and on Monday.”` it will run every day of the week AND on Monday.

Answer (score -2):

```
0 9 1-7 * 1 *
```

This will work for every monday of every month.

Comment: An answer has been accepted, is your answer better, different or useful on a newer version, etc.