# How to set cron expression to run first Weekday (MON-FRI) and first Weekend (SAT-SUN) of the month?

Tags: cron

I tried for the Weekend (SAT-SUN) cron expression:

```
0 0 18 ? 1/1 SAT#1,SUN#1 *
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you really mean first weekday *and* first weekend?  So if the month starts on a Sunday, you want the script to run on Sunday and Monday?

Comment: Yes Paul I want to set a cron expression for first weekend and first weekdays. Without using any script can I achieve?

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676475/run-every-monday-at-5am

Answer (score 2):

You don't say which CRON version you are using but from my limited experience generally the CRON Configuration is -

Min Hour Day Month Day-of-Week followed by your command to execute

so on the first day of month this would be 0 0 1 * * not starting 0 0 18

One solution is that you could use the syntax of the bash case... esac statement

```
0 0 1,2,3 * * case `date "+\%w\%d"` in \\[1-5]\\01|\\1\\02|\\1\\03) /path/to/your/script ;; esac
```

The cron entry is then checked against the "case word in" value of the expression until a match is found. If nothing matches, the default condition will be used.

Bash  Basic date format $date “+
Where Parameter from the list below and separator is a any field separator like hyphen( – ) , slash , colon :   and it is optional.

Bash Date Format Examples
%d is keyword for two digit date
%w day of week starting with Sunday (0), i.e. smtwtfs (note sunday can be both 0 and 7).

Here the string word is compared against every pattern until a match is found. The statement(s) following the matching pattern executes. If no matches are found, the case statement exits without performing any action.

When statement(s) part executes, the command ;; indicates that flow should jump to the end of the entire case statement.

so if the date is 01 on a monday to friday or (day 1) monday is the date 02 or 03 of month then run your script at 00:00 hrs otherwise do nothing

or for the weekend

```
0 0 1 * * case `date "+\%w\%d"` in \\0\\01|\\6\\01|\\6\\02|\\6\\03|\\6\\04|\\6\\05|\\6\\06|\\6\\07) /path/to/your/script ;; esac
```

Otherwise but not all CRON work the same you could also try the following options.

For Every Saturday OR Sunday if it is the  1st to 7th

```
0 0 1-7 * 6,7

0 0 1-7 * SAT,SUN
```

First Weekday of Month

```
0 0 1W * *
```

First Saturday OR Sunday if it is the  1st to 7th

```
0 0 1-7 * 6#1,7#1   

0 0 1-7 * SAT#1,SUN#1
```